# How can i get service locator in hydrator strategy class?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I want to get service locator in my hydrator strategy class. here is my strategy class:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Model\Strategies;

use Application\Model\Tables\Entity;
use Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\Strategy\StrategyInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class carBrandStrategy implements StrategyInterface, ServiceLocatorAwareInterface  {
    protected $services;

    public function extract($value) {
        return "hi";
    }

    public function hydrate($value) {
        $entity = new Entity($this->getServiceLocator);
        $tableCarBrands = $entity->getRepository("CarBrands");
        return $tableCarBrands->find($value);
    }

    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) {
        $this->services = $serviceLocator;
    }

    public function getServiceLocator() {
        return $this->services;
    }
}
```

i found that i can access to service locator with ServiceLocatorInterface, but i can't use it. thanks for help

Comment: I dont think Thats what hydrators are for. Ontopic: You forgot the brackets () at line 16.

Answer (score 2):

in zf2 hydrator are used to hydrate data sets from php `objects` to an `array` or vise versa to populate data from `arrays` into the `object`.

that is all, there is no reason to inject the servicemanager into an hydrator by default in zf2. you try to process this data in a way normal hydrators in zf2 are not primary designed for.

you call an entity and `getRepository` so i think you use `Doctrine`. If so look at the `DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject` class to bind your form data into an doctrine entity.